# Functional Creating a list based on values in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I have a task to traverse a sequence of tuples and based on last value in the tuple make 1 or more copies of a case class Item. I can solve this task with foreach and Mutable List. As I'm learning FP and Scala collections could it be done more functional way with immutable collections and high order functions in Scala?

For example, input:

```
List[("A", 2), ("B", 3), ...]
```

Output:

```
List[Item("A"), Item("A"), Item("B"),Item("B"),Item("B"), ...]
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted -2?  It's an ok question.

Comment: Yay! It's in the positive. In fact I thought it was such a good question, I will use it my Scala classes. Tough to find a good simple flatMap based question and answer.

Comment: @DanielHinojosa wish people make comments after downwoting to figure out what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each tuple `flatMap` using `List.fill[A](n: Int)(elem: ⇒ A)` which produces a `List` of `elem` `n` times.

```
scala> val xs = List(("A", 2), ("B", 3), ("C", 4))
xs: List[(String, Int)] = List((A,2), (B,3), (C,4))

scala> case class Item(s: String)
defined class Item

scala> xs.flatMap(x => List.fill(x._2)(Item(x._1)))
res2: List[Item] = List(Item(A), Item(A), Item(B), Item(B), Item(B), Item(C), Item(C), Item(C), Item(C))
```

Comment: Great call with `fill`!

Answer (score 1):

Using `flatten` for `case class Item(v: String)` as follows

```
myList.map{ case(s,n) => List.fill(n)(Item(s)) }.flatten
```

Also with a for comprehension like this,

```
for ( (s,n) <- myList ; l <- List.fill(n)(Item(s)) ) yield l
```

which is syntax sugar for a call to `flatMap`.

In addition to `List.fill` consider List.tabulate for initialising lists, for instance in this way,

```
for ( (s,n) <- myList ; l <- List.tabulate(n)(_ => Item(s)) ) yield l
```

Comment: nice solution with for comprehension! @enzyme